# Giving a guest user in Azure access to a VM

Tags: azure, entra-id

I have given an external user access to a full resource group in Azure using these instructions:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-external-users, with the exception of connecting a specific app (like the Salesforce app in the example).

The external user says they cannot access it.

When I check the rights assignments within Azure, the user has "Contributor" role to the entire Resource Group.

Did I do something wrong (i.e., I need to do something else) or should this be sufficient?

Comment: You need to get more specific information from the user. Otherwise you will just go on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Like Michael wrote, we need more info to help. Is the user able to press the “connect” button and start a RDP/SSH session? An error after he/she provided username/password? And so on...

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try and source more info and update the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a user being able to RDP to a VM, the access you grant in the portal is not related to the access to connect to the VM its self. The Portal rights give the user access to manage the VM in Azure, but when it comes to authenticating on the VM this is going to use either local user accounts on the VM, or if it is domain joined, then domain accounts.

You need to create and provide credentials to the user for the VM.